# read another xml file and sort based on element sequence order in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
            with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
            of the world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
            society in England, the young survivors lay the 
            foundation for a new society.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk104">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
        <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
            agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
            for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
            Ascendant.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk105">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
        <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
            battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
            Oberon's Legacy.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk106">
        <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
        <title>Lover Birds</title>
        <genre>Romance</genre>
        <price>4.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
        <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
            conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk107">
        <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
        <title>Splish Splash</title>
        <genre>Romance</genre>
        <price>4.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
        <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
            thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk108">
        <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
        <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
        <genre>Horror</genre>
        <price>4.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
        <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
            centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk109">
        <author>Kress, Peter</author>
        <title>Paradox Lost</title>
        <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
        <price>6.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
        <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
            Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
            of being quantum.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk110">
        <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
        <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>36.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
        <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
            detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk111">
        <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
        <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>36.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
        <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
            detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
            SAX and more.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="external" select="document('order.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="division" match="book" use="genre" />
    <xsl:key name="genere_external" match="order" use="$external//genre"/>
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="$external/order/genre"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
       <html>
           <head>
           <title>My library</title>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=UINhlnIwABSJ7C8Qh8aCdf0TQKFZ8WQ499hwuHHAuQLS-882A1wtWYep9T-zt8uVm67ksiZ3XR9POxVQ4kLjukYIcaKBRwHa-LU9i6kDH-U095fchiLJQCpjK4C7HpidmEsB2hC0xdXXJGnoGOlBdspd_oOvYzxc0xhnEg-UCbYmH1KZHqommvit4jo41hf0CSfzLVB1OJ_u9tkvV3giA5fHWUO5Fu6M75pWwf8scROVAqGcb91WuOwtxj6CclTbD-5xIxwAWduoHAbMgFIbBxKwd6VoSQ9-CGkVSQz1LqWrBpka5CY59VZD5pqe_972-UxhhX3cz0pBenkEDHJKcutnm-PgxzMtpAMrS7lJ2b62kitXdTO6oQpBPtLlZHGRLujvb45dUvPsZJxLc7C0kuYHrOdbNdA3WP-dD7oLDB1C0dG4O7a4RJucCRpNJJbmvl8FB_W-4fswodF_MTHTefZ_y9YtPMTIOBvGY4XL-WtHpmBpg_z9FQ96NI7z16O7-JcjVqFxnsXQa5hirHeQ4QkLN5DNo2LMdP45qLFB7L4lf28xJwX79v7l_wy5Wy3XW4CwX8OoK5UpVSGNXIkMAM4kwkBG5tD5m_kzRonw1h7OpKAF4kajwGrCW-NTSOca733w8yfhY_1DhQMNamosNEolD66Epyc-5epeYR0-mVFVTwB0dvCMB1K6KrWyllZHLVIwVLekuJ4OdtJN0AxTP_nAeiUL6lY0l2hO38djLYDpMCjOMtJRU83-CV-_jXBixQ2g3jUyquua21emQuMWOG-gUXmCT29v3QcyWVbYTX1q9rXrpXnAPtZ4mdw65_hlrqiq35dX_g7zfTMjK-2mwZtF9mu5Wy66IsE8MK_gZZ_FZb4k6UQ1-YJiITEosaM5n-kk2djHI23DhA56Ghyh_UKBbOA31AvTMGAyGXURuRhunMdW1HFnZO6-zKY3ftdB4LDIR0-r1BPOzHQxaW888K6g5MVu65XJIBPYY3eWipNXwf02A--3SHsrVxTCc5zzK7Tcwns0qKG6rsUgQbcuPhVYEFpWfSQug-QORqttPiYUHxtDiM6cKS5vsFYsyZ_nF-ITvmOhLreD_KTzOIyTly480eY8LTG2Y9cL0MAeDRgbUzQmptMcULhB0J3F6b7bOqHrTcky6PMbheBKUXRnSbSIsFY_w-38h8aCKy0kYQ0" nonce="f2c81066605e7c336012f856c4fd7140" charset="UTF-8"></script><style type="text/css">body {width: 90%;margin-left: 5%;color: #666;font-family: Verdana;}.rack {width: 100%;float: left;margin-bottom: 1em;border: 1px solid;}.rack h2 {text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #278b31;color: #fff;margin: 0;padding: 1%;letter-spacing: 2px;}.book {border: 1px solid;padding: 5px;width: 30%;float: left;min-height: 200px;margin: 1%;background-color: #eaeaea;border-radius: 5%;}span.field {margin-right: 2px;color: #369ac9;}</style>
           </head>
           <body>
               <div class="container">
                   <h1>MY LIBRARY</h1>
                   <xsl:for-each select="book[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('division', genre))]">

                      <!-- <xsl:sort select="genre"/>-->

                       <div class="wall">
                           <!-- <Division value="{genre}">-->
                           <div class="rack">
                               <h2><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></h2>

                               <xsl:for-each select="key('division', genre) ">
                                   <div class="book">
                                       <div class="author">
                                           <span class="field">Author: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></span>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="title">
                                           <span class="field">Title: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></span>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="genre">
                                           <span class="field">Genre: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></span>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="price">
                                           <span class="field">Price: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></span>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="publish_date">
                                           <span class="field">Publish_date: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="publish_date"/></span>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="description">
                                           <span class="field">Description: </span>
                                           <span class="value"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></span>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                           </div>
                           <!--</Division>-->
                       </div>
                   </xsl:for-each>

               </div>

           </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

Let us put this list outside your XSLT file. Let's say "order.xml". The XSLT code should read
 this XML and organize books in this order. We should be able to change this order and if we rerun        the XSLT code, the output should be as expected.if i change the sequence of genre in order.xml         file, In that sequence output will come. how to write the code

order.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>

    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <genre>Horror</genre>
</order>
```

`plz help me sortout this problem`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to sort anything when the genres are already sorted in the order you want them to be. Simply list the genres as given, followed by a list of books in each genre.

Here is a minimized example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="input-xml" select="/"/>
<xsl:param name="genres" select="document('order.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="book-by-genre" match="book" use="genre" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>MY LIBRARY</h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="$genres/order/genre">
                <xsl:variable name="genre" select="." />
                <!-- switch context back to input XML -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$input-xml">
                    <xsl:variable name="books-in-genre" select="key('book-by-genre', $genre)" />
                    <xsl:if test="$books-in-genre">
                         <h2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$genre"/>
                         </h2>
                         <xsl:for-each select="$books-in-genre">
                             <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                             </p>
                         </xsl:for-each>     
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>MY LIBRARY</h1>
<h2>Fantasy</h2>
<p>Midnight Rain</p>
<p>Maeve Ascendant</p>
<p>Oberon's Legacy</p>
<p>The Sundered Grail</p>
<h2>Science Fiction</h2>
<p>Paradox Lost</p>
<h2>Romance</h2>
<p>Lover Birds</p>
<p>Splish Splash</p>
<h2>Computer</h2>
<p>XML Developer's Guide</p>
<p>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</p>
<p>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</p>
<h2>Horror</h2>
<p>Creepy Crawlies</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Rendered**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A @michaelhor257k points out you can implement this as a join rather than a sort. But it can also be done using `xsl:sort`, at least with XSLT 2.0+: `<xsl:sort select="index-of($genres, genre)"/>` where $genres is the list of genres as a sequence of strings.

When you submit XSLT questions to this site (or anywhere) please make it clear whether you have a any constraints on which version of the language you are using. Many things become much easier in later versions of the language, but sadly many users are still on the original version 1.0.